# Deleting a line except the start string using sed command

Tags: sed

I want to delete an entire line except the start string . My file looks like:

> CAM_READ_0623233313 /library_id=CAM_LIB_002149 /sample_id=CAM_SMPL_003380 raw_id=G9ALM7U02GRHFF length=72 /IP_notice=?This genetic information downloaded from CAMERA may be considered to be part of the genetic patrimony of Denmark, the country from which the sample was obtained.  Users of this information agree to:  1) acknowledge Denmark as the country of origin in any country where the genetic information is presented and 2) contact the CBD focal point identified on the CBD website (http://www.cbd.int/countries/) if they intend to use the genetic information for commercial purposes.?
>   AGGTAGTTTCCTCTACAGACTCTGCTATTTTCATCCGTGCGTCTTCGCGGCCGGTCCAGAGCGCGCCCCACG

My final output should be :

> CAM_READ_0623233313 
>   AGGTAGTTTCCTCTACAGACTCTGCTATTTTCATCCGTGCGTCTTCGCGGCCGGTCCAGAGCGCGCCCCACG

How can I do this with sed command?
There are no line breaks in between and the format is the same.
Whenever I try all the lines merge into single one.

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you google a bit before asking?

Comment: It's not clear whether your input string has a line break or not. Be more precise. Looks like you could just remove anything between the first `space`and the last `?`... It would also help if you would say what parts of the input string are always of the same format.

Comment: whenever I try all the lines merge into a single line which is not the output required. Please excuse I am not a master in regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat data 
CAM_READ_0623233313 /library_id=CAM_LIB_002149 /sample_id=CAM_SMPL_003380 raw_id=G9ALM7U02GRHFF length=72 /IP_notice=?This genetic information downloaded from CAMERA may be considered to be part of the genetic patrimony of Denmark, the country from which the sample was obtained. Users of this information agree to: 1) acknowledge Denmark as the country of origin in any country where the genetic information is presented and 2) contact the CBD focal point identified on the CBD website (http://www.cbd.int/countries/) if they intend to use the genetic information for commercial purposes.? AGGTAGTTTCCTCTACAGACTCTGCTATTTTCATCCGTGCGTCTTCGCGGCCGGTCCAGAGCGCGCCCCACG
$ sed -r 's/^(\w+).*\?(\s*\w+)$/\1\2/g' data 
CAM_READ_0623233313 AGGTAGTTTCCTCTACAGACTCTGCTATTTTCATCCGTGCGTCTTCGCGGCCGGTCCAGAGCGCGCCCCACG
$
```

Comment: @meenalm I've used the data which you have provided in your question, can you post your whole data?

Comment: I need an inplace file edit with the file.The pattern repeats to a file size of 600 MB

Comment: just add `-i` for in place file edit i.e use `sed -r -i ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1,$NF > (FILENAME) }' file
```

Print the first and last field.

Comment: @sjsam: there are no line breaks and the pattern repeats to a file size of 600 MB.

Comment: @meenalm . Are you using gnu-awk?